# How to modify menu text in callback function of 'walker_nav_menu_start_el' hook

Tags: menus, filters, hooks

I am trying to modify the menu text in callback function of 'walker_nav_menu_start_el' hook.

```
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse3401_modify_menu_text', 10, 4);

function wpse3401_modify_menu_text( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args )
{

    /*
     Want to write logic here to modify the menu text. It is available
     in $item->title
    */

    return $item_output;
}
```

I have tried to modify the text `$item->title` but it does not work.

`$item_output` contains HTML markup with anchor tag, that's why I am not able to modify the text only.

**Edit:**

I am trying to modify menu text as below

`$item->title = $item->title . ' -'`. added this code inside the above callback

Comment: Simply, `$item->title = $item->title . ' -'`,  in above callback before returning `$item_output`. @MaxYudin

Comment: @MaxYudin, Added that information

Comment: I updated the code this will give you `Title -` for `Title`.I don't know what do you want to do adding ` - ` to the menu title.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to modify html markup and change menu title you can create your own `walker_nav` class as below. Here i put the fontawesome icon `fa-home` icon for `Home`  menu and more icons before dropdown menus.

```
class Sunrise_Universal_Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_menu {

    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ){ //ul
        $indent = str_repeat("\t",$depth);
        $submenu = ($depth > 0) ? ' sub-menu' : '';
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu $submenu depth_$depth\">\n";
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){ //li a span

        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat("\t",$depth) : '';

        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';

        // look you can put home icon for home page  and what not
        if($item->title == 'Home'){
            $item->title = '<span class="fa fa-home"></span>';
        }


        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        /*echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($item);
        die();*/
        $classes[] = ($args->walker->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
        $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_ancestor) ? 'active' : '';
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
        if( $depth && $args->walker->has_children ){
            $classes[] = 'dropdown-submenu';
        }
        $numbers[] = get_post_meta($item->ID,'_menu_item_object_id',true);

        //here i use the glyphicon for the menus of dropdown 

        $glyphicon= '';
        foreach ($numbers as $number) {
            if(in_category("services",$number)){
                $glyphicon = get_post_meta($number,"glyphicon",true);
            }
        }
        $class_names =  join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"';

        $id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'.$item->ID, $item, $args);
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';


    $attributes .= 'class="dropdown-toggle"';
            $attributes .= ( $args->walker->has_children ) ? ' class="dropdown-toggle drop-down full-width hover-fade" data-toggle="dropdown"' : '';

            $item_output = $args->before;
//glyhicons are here 

            $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '><span class="glyphicons '.$glyphicon.'"></span>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= ( $depth == 0 && $args->walker->has_children ) ? ' <b class="caret"></b></a>' : '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters ( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

    }

}
```

Then you have to use the code below  at header.php where you want  menu to appear.

```
<nav class="navbar collapse navbar-collapse  navbar-sunshine" id="navbar-collapse-1">

      <?php  wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main', 'theme_location' => 'Primary','container' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="main-menu">%3$s</ul>' , 'walker' => new Sunrise_Universal_Walker_Nav_Primary())); ?>                        
</nav>
```

Update:
If you don't want to use `walker_nav` class do something like this

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {

    preg_match_all('~>\K[^<>]*(?=</a)~', $items, $matches);
    $return = $items;
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {

        $return = preg_replace('@'.$match.'@', $match.' -', $return);

    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is the correct answer